# Simplifying Expression with Infinite Sum of Delta Functions convolved with Exponential Function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, convolution, dirac-delta

I need some help with simplifying the following expression:

$$\sum_{n= -\infty }^\infty \delta(t-2n) \ast e^{-2t}u(t)$$

Using the convolution integral and taking the unit step into account, I get:

$$\int_{0}^\infty\sum_{n=0 }^\infty \delta(t-2n)e^{-2{(t-\tau)}}d\tau $$

Simplifying further results in:

$$e^{-2t}\sum_{n=0 }^\infty \delta(t-2n)\int_{0}^\infty e^{2\tau}d\tau $$

The integral $\int_{0}^\infty e^{2\tau}d\tau $ does not converge, so I'm unsure if I made a mistake somewhere or if this is what the expression $\sum_{n= -\infty }^\infty \delta(t-2n) \ast e^{-2t}u(t)$ simplifies to.

Can someone verify my work or point me in the right direction?

Comment: The original sum looks unclear to me. We convolve functions, not values, but $\delta(t-2n)$ and $e^{-2t}$ and $u(t)$ are values of (generalized) functions at a specific point.

Comment: The lower integration limit for the convolution integral is $-\infty$, not $0$, and the result of the convolution is $\left[\delta(t-2n) \ast e^{-2t}\, u(t)\right](\tau)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(t-2n)\, e^{-2 (\tau-t)}\, u(\tau-t)\,d\tau=e^{-2 (\tau -2 n)} u(\tau -2 n)$ independent of whether $u(t)$ is the Heaviside step function $\theta(t)$ or a regular function.